# Phonegap: sounds playing in simulator but not in iPad

Tags: ipad, audio, cordova

I've this Phonegap app that on certain events should play an audio file. This audio is heard when trying the app in the iPad simulator, but not on a proper iPad (and I know for certain that other sounds are being heard)

I've included phonegap*.js in the head section:

```
<head>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
    <script 
        type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
        src="scripts/phonegap-1.3.0.js">
    </script>
    <script 
        type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" >
    </script>
</head>
```

and this is the function that should play audio files:

```
function playAudio(audio_file) {
    switch (audio_file) {
    case 'right':
        new Media('media/audio/right.wav').play();
        break;
    case 'timer' :
        new Media('media/audio/timer.wav').play();
        break;
    case 'complete':
        new Media('media/audio/complete.wav').play();
        break;
    }
}
```

something pretty simple. No weird formats, just wavs. Could it be something to the path not being properly defined for the device? Remember: they work in the simulator. And even in Safari they raise an "ERROR: Attempting to call PhoneGap.exec() before 'deviceready'. Ignoring.", so they are being called.

Comment: I don't do PhoneGap (yet), but it sounds to me like the `Media` objects can't find the .wav files.  If there's any way to query them to see if they have successfully loaded or found a media file, you should do that before playing them.

Comment: Is the "ERROR: Attempting to call PhoneGap.exec() before 'deviceready'. Ignoring" a symptom? Or from a different test scenario? If it's a symptom this seems pretty clear - a race condition, phonegap's not ready.

Comment: Media objects are able to find those files in the iPad simulator, but I'll try to query them and give some visual feedback just in case - thanks for the idea, Michael.

Comment: djna, no, it's just that Safari doesn't know what to do with PhoneGap. It's just a probe that those lines are being called correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert your sounds to mp3's. Also you may want to localize your jQuery. You are essentially requiring a connection for your app to work...

Comment: You're right, I have to put jQuery on a local file. I thought I had already done that ;)

I'll try with mp3 and report back.

Comment: Sorry Drew, it didn't work. No sound, yet. I just don't know what I'm doing wrong - and I know for certain that one of my first tests worked flawlessly. It's even more puzzling knowing that it works in the simulator! :(

Comment: that's very strange. This is what I have used before - 
`playing = new Media("sounds/"+s+'.mp3');
playing.play();`

s is my sound file name. Maybe try doing something similar - rather than setting the play when you declare the sound make it variable and then apply the play() to that?

Comment: No, no sounds yet. I'm running out of options here... And I even tried creating them before playing, though as a global variable. I'll try right before calling play()